# How to use mouse scroll as an event to simulate a click

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, hello everyone, I am a python, sort of beginner, programmer and recently I have the problem that for some reasons, I wanna use the mouse scroll wheel as a left-click, basically, rotating the scroll wheel once simulates the left click(or any key/click) once, I have been having difficulty in doing this so any help would be appreciated!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please share what you have tried so far to make problem more clear for others otherwise no one will code for you.

Comment: been trying to find stuff but failed so practically i have done nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install mouse package

```
pip install mouse
```

And then send custom mouse events to your program.

```
# scroll down
mouse.wheel(-1)

# scroll up
mouse.wheel(1)

# left click
mouse.click('left')

# right click
mouse.click('right')

# middle click
mouse.click('middle')
```

take a look at: https://pypi.org/project/mouse/

Comment: But won't that just simulate a scroll event? I want to record a scroll event

Comment: Read the mouse doc and you can accomplish that. https://github.com/boppreh/mouse#mouse.record

Comment: Thanks dude but this will be inefficient because ill have to first record the scrolls, process them and then simulate, any way to keep them real time?